# Line integral on complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to solve this integral integral

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2},\quad \gamma(t)=e^{it}\text{ and } 0 \leq t\leq 2\pi$$

My attempt:

$$f(\gamma(t))=\frac{e^{ie^{it}}}{{(e^{it})}^2}={(e^i)^{e^{it}-2t}} \text{ and } 
\gamma'(t)=ie^{it}$$

So
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}= \int_{o}^{2\pi}{(e^i)^{e^{it}-2t}} \cdot ie^{it}=i\int_{o}^{2\pi}{(e^i)^{e^{it}-t}}$$

from here I don't know how to continue, it's probably something basic, but I can't find it.

Comment: You could use Cauchy's Integral Formula for Derivatives

Answer (score 7):

This is best solved by the residue theorem, you have an enclosed pole in the contour. Develop the exponential in its Taylor expansion and observe the residue value at $z = 0$.

$$e^{iz} = 1 + (iz) + \frac{(iz)^2}{2!} + ..$$
Hence
$$
\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} = \frac{1}{z^2}+ \frac{i}{z} - \frac{1}{2!} + ..$$
Hence, the residue at zero is just $i$; there is a simple pole at $z= 0$.

The value of the integral is $2\pi i$ times the sum of the enclosed residues so it's $-2\pi$.